# Change Ubercart's "Order" to "Donation"

Tags: ubercart, i18n-l10n

I am setting up a site for a non-profit organization (using Ubercart to accept donations) and I want to change "order" to "donation".

I started in with the stringoverrides module. I was searching around trying to find all the occurrences of "Order" and putting in a string over ride that changed it to "Donation". I found this to be extremely clunky, time consuming and error prone.

I looked at the source of the string overrides module figuring that I could find how it was actually performing the override and then hack together my own solution to programmatically do some sort of search and replace on it. After looking at that and the source for the `t()` function I realized it wasn't going to be that easy.

1. Is there a way to easily pull a list of all the `t()` calls that include the text "order" in them? I could then pretty easily generate a .po file by doing a bunch of search and replace type operations.
2. Is there a way to programmatically change all occurrences of 'order' to 'donation'?
3. Is there some other obvious way that I haven't thought of?

P.S. I am proficient with custom module development in Drupal but don't have much experience in [l10n_update](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_update) or [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) with Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at this http://drupal.org/project/uc_donation... Ubercart can actually provide donation functionality. Let me know if this is what you were thinking.

Comment: I actually am using that module. What it does is provide a custom product type to Ubercart that you can specify the price but not the quantity. What I am looking for is literally changing every occurrence of the string "order" to "donation".